# how to generate a vector of the sign of each elements from another vector without using sign function

Tags: r

I have this vector

```
y <- c(3, 3, -5, -1)
```

I want to find out sign of each element without using sign function,
so new generated vector as follows `'p'` for positive and `'n'` for negative
as a result 
I want to create vector

```
# 'p' 'p' 'n' 'n'
```

how to do this in R programming?

Answer (score 1):

We can try using `ifelse` for a base R option:

```
y <- c(3,3,-5,-1)
y_sign <- ifelse(y < 0, "n", "p")
y_sign

[1] "p" "p" "n" "n"
```

If we wanted to also have a separate label `z` for exactly zero, then we can try:

```
y_sign <- ifelse(y == 0, "z", ifelse(y < 0, "n", "p"))
```